# update json fields using apex_json package in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

I'd like to update values in a json using oracle apex only.
First I'll extract from the input, using get_number and then I need to update the value in the existing column

```
DECLARE 
    j apex_json.t_values; 
BEGIN 
    apex_json.parse(j, '{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Total   : ' || APEX_JSON.get_number( 'total'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('netAmmount:'||APEX_JSON.get_number( 'netAmmount'));
    -- im looking for something like this below    
  UPDATE t SET json_column = apex_write(APEX_JSON.get_number( 'total'));
END;
```

Please  help

Answer (score 0):

You lack the parameter p_value:

```
DECLARE 
    j apex_json.t_values; 
    v apex_json.t_value; 
BEGIN 
    apex_json.parse(j, '{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}'); 
    v := apex_json.get_value(p_path=>'total',p_values=>j); 
    dbms_output.put_line(v.number_value);

    UPDATE t SET json_column =  v.number_value;
END;
```

Comment: It's returning null, instead of the value 83.

Comment: `DECLARE
    j   apex_json.t_values;
BEGIN
    apex_json.parse(j, '{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}');
    dbms_output.put_line('total:'
                         || apex_json.get_number(p_path => 'total', p0 => 1, p_values => j));
--table t, json_value column has data same as above
 UPDATE t
    SET
        json_column = apex_json.get_number(p_path => 'total', p0 => 1, p_values => j);

END;`  Ii am able to extract the data but I don't think its working in the update  @IDA

Comment: You should assign the result to the variable, then use that variable in the update statement

Comment: Still not working. If you could give me a working example, it will help a lot. Thanks!! @IDA

Comment: I want only the `total` value updated in the whole json structure, not the whole column. my table column already has a value of `'{"total":100,"netAmmount":65}'`. so this needs to be updated to `'{"total":83,"netAmmount":65}'`